# When something should happen in future, but it is expressed in present tense

Tags: grammar

I am a little bit confused and not a native speaker.
When something should happen in the future (e.g. if you set yourself a goal), but you state it like **it has already happened**. How do you call this tense?
For example here these sentences:

> "A data management system is implemented."
>
> "The capacities of private and public stakeholders are strengthened."
>
> "New or improved approaches promoting specific activities are tested."
>
> "Options for a sustainable improvement of the train service quality are developed."
>
> "Evaluations with options for replication are available."
>
> "A jointly developed market model is available."
>
> "Further implementation by the municipality is decided."
>
> "Internationally proven approaches are demonstrated for the first time"

**Questions**:

Is it legit to use this tense or should I stick to another tense within these sentences?
Is there a name of this tense? (Present Future Continuous? Is there something like that?)

Comment: I can't tell what context you're using these sentences in. By themselves they just seem like present statements without a clear connection to any future actions.

Comment: These are just present statements; do you mean something like *In Phase III, a data management system is implemented.* ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the present tense, specifically the *passive* present in your examples, in a future context.  However, to do this properly you have to adequately describe the context to the listener so they understand the point of view.  In effect, you are narrating future events *as if they are happening in the moment*.

For example (as Davo suggests):

> Next year we plan to implement a multi-phase operation to update our systems.  In Phase I of the operation, the data management system **is brought** online and **deployed** to millions of customers throughout the world.  In Phase II, new features **are introduced** to customers as they **are rolled out**.  In Phase III a new customer interface **replaces** the existing portal.

Again, the important thing is to establish the proper context, otherwise the use of the present tense is awkward and sounds ungrammatical.